# Area that can be explored when tied to a hexagonal fence

Tags: geometry

Larry the Llama is tied to one of the vertices of a regular hexagonal fence. Larry's leash measures 12 and the side length of the fence measures 4. Given that he can't enter the area enclosed by the fence, the total area that Larry has to roam with his leash on is 3A. Find A. (Assume that he remains on the ground and the length of the rope remains constant.)

-Taken from rickardsinvitational.org
2013 Geo indiv test

Comment: Hint: The total grazing area is a union of five circular sections.

Comment: I got - 96 π, 64π/3, and 4π (the latter two can be divided into two smaller, equal, sectors resulting in a total of five sectors) would this be correct?

Comment: 368π/3. So A would be 368π/9 correct? However the answer key says the answer is just 368π...

Comment: I also get $\frac{368}{9}\pi$.  The part with $3A$ is a bit bizarre, and I get the feeling your textbook got some wording backwards from what was intended.

Comment: I think you should give a reference for where you got this problem from. Looks like http://www.rickardsinvitational.org/2013%20tests/Geo_Indiv.pdf. This is also important in terms of copyright.

Comment: Oh ok ill include the source in my next question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we assume not only that Larry can't enter the fenced area, but neither can his leash, then the leash has to wrap around the corners of the fence, shortening its length. Therefore the area reachable to the llama would look like this:

[image: Figure]

The areas of the different parts are as follows:

- Red: one sector of $240°$ and radius $12$: $\frac23\cdot\pi\cdot12^2$
- Green: two sectors of $60°$ each and radius $8$: $2\cdot\frac16\cdot\pi\cdot8^2$
- Yellow: two sectors of $60°$ each and radius $4$: $2\cdot\frac16\cdot\pi\cdot4^2$

Sum everything up and you get an area of

$$3A=\frac{368}{3}\pi$$

I have no idea why you'd want to divide that by three, i.e. why the problem statement calls this area $3A$ instead of $A$, but the correct answer would apparently be

$$A=\frac{368}{9}\pi\approx 128.456$$

as some comments already indicated.

Looking at [this likely source](http://www.rickardsinvitational.org/2013%20tests/Geo_Indiv.pdf) I see $368\pi$ as a possible answer in this multiple-choice test. So perhaps they wanted to call the computed area $A$ and the answer to tick to be $3A$, so that you'd have to multiply instead of divide. Or they wanted to deliberately confuse readers.

Comment: Nice picture~~~